# WPF Combobox text binding issue on tab chage

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, binding

I am working in a WPF application which follows MVVM.

I have used binding in Combobox's text property and this combo is inside a tab.

When ever I switch tabs, Combobox's text property cahnged is getting fired and text is set to string.Empty.

Comment: may be because the binding text is getting null on tab index change

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the text to ever be empty, you could try:

View
`<ComboBox Text={Binding ComboxText} ... />`

Edit from Comment:
`<ComboBox Text={Binding ComboxText, TargetNullValue=SomeValue} ... />`

ViewModel

```
/*INotifyPropertyChanged property*/
private string comboxText;
public string ComboxText 
{  get { return comboxText; }  
   set { 
      if (value != comboxText)  
      {// value changed ->  
         if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))   
         {// value not null, empty, whitespace ->  
            comboxText = value;
         }  
         /*INPC code*/
      }  
   }
}
```

Comment: Ya I had used like this as a work around but is there any better solution for this

Comment: You could also try using a TargetNullValue on the Binding.  See edited code above.  
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx